# Double Coset Space

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In the theory of Shimura varieties you construct the variety as a double coset space $G(\mathbb{Q}) \backslash  X \times G(\mathbb{A}_f) / K$ . I do not understand this as a variety. I thought you could not take quotients of varieties?

Comment: It is not a quotient of a variety. As I understand it, this construction generalizes the construction of the moduli space of elliptic curves as a quotient of the upper half-plane; there the quotient is a complex manifold (more or less) but it takes extra work to show that it can be given the additional structure of a complex variety. See, for example, http://www.ams.org/journals/notices/201211/rtx121101560p.pdf.

Comment: I was searching while waiting for an answer as well and I came across this (http://www.jmilne.org/math/articles/1995b.pdf), just to confirm you answer. Thanks! @QiaochuYuan